# Как создать полу дугу

Tags: css, css3

Как создать полу дугу, создаю дугу с помощью `border-bottom:1px solid #000;` это полная дуга, а как сделать ее половинку(или больше половины), идея такая 30% этой дуги желтая, остальная зеленая.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205652/how-to-draw-a-circle-sector-in-css

Comment: Стоп, этот код создает рамку внизу блока высотой 1 px и цветом #000.Я могу предположить что ты еще указал border-radius , но в таком случае нужно сделать две рамик

Comment: можно в два div но чтоб они выгледели как дуги, две.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.b-circle{
  margin: 15px auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.b-circle:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.b-circle > span{
  position: absolute;
}
.b-circle > span:nth-of-type(1){
  top: 0; height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  /*background: #FD6347;*/
}
.b-circle > span:nth-of-type(1):before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
.b-circle > span:nth-of-type(1):after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 30%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.b-circle > span:nth-of-type(2){
  top: 50%; 
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #008080;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-circle">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Как вариант

```css
#semiarc {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 10px solid #ff8040;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: visible;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#semiarc > div {
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;    
    border-radius: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    margin: -10px auto auto -10px;
    border: 10px solid #060;
    clip: rect(0, 200px, 100px, 0);    
}
```

```html
<div id="semiarc">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

```html
<svg>
  <path fill="none" stroke="#333333" stroke-width="3" d="M10,55 C15,5 100,5 100,55" />
</svg>
```

Вот так

ps:
 svg это мощь

```html
<svg width="215px" height="274px" viewBox="0 0 215 274">
    <g>
        <path class="stems" fill="none" stroke="#7AA20D" stroke-width="8" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M54.817,169.848c0,0,77.943-73.477,82.528-104.043c4.585-30.566,46.364,91.186,27.512,121.498" />
        <path class="leaf" fill="#7AA20D" stroke="#7AA20D" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M134.747,62.926c-1.342-6.078,0.404-12.924,5.762-19.681c11.179-14.098,23.582-17.539,40.795-17.846 c0.007,0,22.115-0.396,26.714-20.031c-2.859,12.205-5.58,24.168-9.774,36.045c-6.817,19.301-22.399,48.527-47.631,38.028 C141.823,75.784,136.277,69.855,134.747,62.926z" />
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="r-cherry" fill="#ED6E46" stroke="#ED6E46" stroke-width="12" d="M164.836,193.136 c1.754-0.12,3.609-0.485,5.649-1.148c8.512-2.768,21.185-6.985,28.181,3.152c15.076,21.845,5.764,55.876-18.387,66.523 c-27.61,12.172-58.962-16.947-56.383-45.005c1.266-13.779,8.163-35.95,26.136-27.478   C155.46,191.738,159.715,193.485,164.836,193.136z" />
        <path class="l-cherry" fill="#ED6E46" stroke="#ED6E46" stroke-width="12" d="M55.99,176.859 c1.736,0.273,3.626,0.328,5.763,0.135c8.914-0.809,22.207-2.108,26.778,9.329c9.851,24.647-6.784,55.761-32.696,60.78 c-29.623,5.739-53.728-29.614-44.985-56.399c4.294-13.154,15.94-33.241,31.584-20.99C47.158,173.415,50.919,176.062,55.99,176.859z" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

это малая часть что можно делать на нём